# Google Maps API: how to open a URL link when clicking the marker - the markers in a mySql database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dom, google-maps-markers

I have created google map and have markers for some restaurants with names and addresses. The markers are being picked up from a mysql database.

I am trying to put a URL link for the restaurant behind the name on the marker so that if you click on a marker it will open the browser to their website.

This is the html code for the map:

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.8980, -8.4737),
          zoom: 16
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

          downloadUrl('locator.php', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
              var id = markerElem.getAttribute('id');
              var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');
              var address = markerElem.getAttribute('address');
              var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
                  parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = name
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            });
          });
        }


      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }
```

I have tried to add a link variable to the database and get it to appear on the marker using this code but it did not work. Is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: How did you try to add the URL/link to the infowindow?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've got a `url` value in the response from your AJAX request.  Just add that as a property to each marker, and amend the click event handler to redirect to that URL:

```
downloadUrl('locator.php', function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
      var type = markerElem.getAttribute('type');
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lat')),
          parseFloat(markerElem.getAttribute('lng')));


      var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        label: icon.label,
        url: markerElem.getAttribute('url');
      });
      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        window.location.href = this.url;
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i have done this however am getting an error: The requested URL /undefined was not found on this server when i click the marker.
 I have put 'url' in the database, for example, 
   INSERT INTO `markers` (`id`, `name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, 
   `url`) VALUES ('1', 'Uncle Petes Pizzaria', '40 Paul St, Centre, Cork', 
   '51.8995', '-8.4741', 'restaurant', 'http://unclepetes.ie/');

And i have added your code. However when i click on the marker i am getting an error. I have changed the format of the URL many times but this does not seem to be the issue?

Comment: What does `console.log(markerElem.getAttribute('url'));` give you?  Can you give us a sample of what `data.responseXML` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I also do not see where you are getting the url for the infowindow. Please try:

```
var url = putYourUrlHereSomehow;
var urlLink = document.createElement("a"); 
urlLink.setAttribute('href', url);       
var t = document.createTextNode(url);       
urlLink.appendChild(t);                                
infowincontent.appendChild(urlLink);
```

This creates a clickable link and sets it  with:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
```